# Table with FOREACH joinable content

Tags: javascript, php, function, pdo, foreach

My problem is that I don't know how to make a function that has the same id as my `$loop['id']` that I created with `foreach` loop.

```
foreach ($getongoing as $loop) {
 echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" . $loop['id'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . $loop['player1'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . "$" . $loop['bet1'] . "</td>";
 echo "<td>" . '<html><img src="images/'.$loop['site1'].'.png" width="25" height="25"/></html>' . "</td>";
```

Within my loops I create a button, which has the `$loop['id']`

```
echo '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onClick="'.$loop['id'].'()" id="test">Join game</button></td></tr>';
```

I would like to make a function/script which comes up with a altert box, asking if I really want to join `$loop['id']` with the bet of `$loop['bet1']`

This is the script that I want to appear when clicking on the specfic join button

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x;
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
        x = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
        x = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of creating and calling function using the value of `$loop['id']`, you can simply pass the value as parameter, see example below:

```
echo '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-link" onClick="myFunction(' . $loop['id'] . ');" id="test">Join game</button></td></tr>';

<script>
function myFunction(id) {
    console.log(id);
    var x;
    if (confirm("Press a button!") == true) {
            x = "You pressed OK!";
    } else {
            x = "You pressed Cancel!";
    }
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: But this comes up being all other buttons linking to the first one?

Comment: No, they have call the same function `myfunction` but you can identify with the help of parameter `id` .. check browser console

Comment: Can we make it, so if i press ok, then it will go to joingame.php?

Comment: `if (confirm("Press a button!")) {window.location = 'joingame.php';}`